# JSONArrays in rows- OPENJSON giving

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I'm really new to Json in SQL, and have been tearing my hair out over this

I have a table [AuditEntries] used for storing audit changes to entities in a json array

```
CREATE TABLE #AuditEntries(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntityType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,   
    [Changes] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL)


INSERT INTO #AuditEntries([Id]
           ,[EntityType]
           ,[Changes])
           VALUES 
( 1, 'Supplier', '["FieldName":"Name","ValueBefore":"Person1","ValueAfter":"Person1a"},{"FieldName":"EmailAddress","ValueBefore":"test1@test.com","ValueAfter":"test1a@test.com"}]',

2, 'Supplier', '["FieldName":"CompanyName","ValueBefore":"Widgets inc","ValueAfter":"Widget and Gubbins inc"},{"FieldName":"EmailAddress","ValueBefore":"test2@test.com","ValueAfter":"test2a@test.com"}]')
```

How can i use OPENJSON() to retrieve the fieldnames that are changed?

With:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON (
   (SELECT Changes from AuditEntries where EntityType = 'Supplier')
) WITH (FieldName NVARCHAR (100) '$.FieldName')
```

I get:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `OPENJSON()` correctly. You may try to use the following statement (note, that the JSON in the question is not correct - missing `{` before the first `"FieldName"`):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #AuditEntries (
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntityType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,   
    [Changes] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO #AuditEntries 
   ([EntityType] ,[Changes])
VALUES 
   ('Supplier', '[{"FieldName":"Name","ValueBefore":"Person1","ValueAfter":"Person1a"},{"FieldName":"EmailAddress","ValueBefore":"test1@test.com","ValueAfter":"test1a@test.com"}]'),
   ('Supplier', '[{"FieldName":"Name","ValueBefore":"Person2","ValueAfter":"Person2a"},{"FieldName":"EmailAddress","ValueBefore":"test2@test.com","ValueAfter":"test2a@test.com"}]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT a.ID, j.FieldName
FROM #AuditEntries a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.Changes) WITH (FieldName varchar(100) '$.FieldName') j
WHERE a.EntityType = 'Supplier'
```

Result:

```
ID  FieldName
1   Name
1   EmailAddress
2   Name
2   EmailAddress
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for that I had tried everything. That's baffled me for 2 days

Comment: @DisplacedWombat Glad to help.